# Create Table Union Between Multiple Data Sources

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

I am working in Crystal Reports 2011 and I am trying to merge two tables from two different data sources into one command to use in a report.

I am having a hard time finding any solid examples online of how to accomplish this inside of a command.  I would expect to use a UNION and it look something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM DSN1.Employee
UNION
SELECT *
FROM DSN2.Employee
```

The two tables are the exact same, just in different databases that I cannot alter or add to.

Any guidance would be a tremendous help.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: So is the UNION not working?

Comment: Please explain how you've configured Crystal Reports to connect to your disparate data sources.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know exactly what you mean by `having a hard time` anyway try something like this ....

Explicitly mention the column names in both selects and use `UNION ALL`, use fully qualified names of your tables something like this....

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, ..... <Other Column Names>
FROM [Database_Name1].[Schema1].[Table_Name1]
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, ..... <Other Column Names>
FROM [Database_Name2].[Schema1].[Table_Name2]
```

using this syntax eliminates most of the possible errors.